# Glade3 - how to set a treestore

Tags: treeview, glade

I want to set a TreeStore to populate a Treeview inside Glade 3 - I mean not programmatically - so that I have a Treestore in the glade XML file.

Is it possible to define a TreeStore (not a ListStore) in Glade 3?

When I right-click on the treeview and get in the treeview editor, it's possible to set a new Treeview Model, but it automatically comes as a ListStore. Is it possible to switch to a TreeStore somewhere?

Couldn't find this answer in the Glade tutorials because there's so few of them and don't cover many functions.

Comment: Any code we can see what you have done?

Comment: @Ibo: this is not a code question at all, it is about Glade's GUI only. I mean, ok I could define the TreeStore outside Glade's XML file but my purpose is to learn how to make it using Glade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is with glade 3.18.3, installed via canonical repositories on ubuntu 16.04:

On the left pane under "Miscellaneous" the second icon is "Tree Store".

[image]

Click that and it will add a new object to your project. In my case called `treestore1`. This will show up on the right under the widget tree.

[image]

Now click on your treeview and see the properties pane (on the right). Under *TreeView Model* click the little pencil edit button:

[image]

and it will popup and let you select your new tree store.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the complete and illustrated answer ! I was convinced there was a way to do it. I just didn't see the menu..